# I have managed to find a way to get text of my slides by using each but how do I get it to display my can products not text?

Tags: javascript, css, function, append, each

I have found a way to display text on each of my empty slides. so far, so good. But at you can see in my codepen project, there's a can displaying on the first slide. Instead of the text 'Hello' on each of my slides, how do I display a loop of cans on each slide?

https://codepen.io/Rosstopherrr/pen/GVRvxJ

I had it like this thinking it will show all cans in each slide but it doesn't show any cans...

```
$('#products article').each(function() {
    $(this).append(initApp())
  });
```

what am I doing wrong?

```
$('#products article').each(function() {
    $(this).append('hello')
  });
```

EDIT - progress so far

so in the each.function(index) - I can add the index, and then in initApp(index) - I can add index. and then in the initApp function I can adjust so that bottle[index] gets selected and then added.
But nothing seems to work?? What am I doing wrong?
I know there is a bunch of ways I can do this.

Like could I skip the initApp() function and add all the code in the .each(function() { my code to append bottle})??

Answer (score 0):

in `initApp()` you define `const $container = getElement('.container')`; `getElement` function calls `document.querySelector(selector);` that returns just **the first** element that matches the selector, in this case the first div with class `.container` in the first `article` tag. That's the first error.

In order to add a bottle to each container you need a list of `.container`s, that you can obtain with `$containers = [...document.querySelectorAll('.container')]`

once you have all `.container` you can integrate the forEach function call, maybe in this way

```
[$bottle1, $bottle2, $bottle3].forEach(($bottle, i) => {
        $bottle.classList.add('bottle' + i);
        $containers[i].append($bottle)
      });
```

it's possible that you will still not find the bottles like in the first item; that's because the single `.bottle1`, `.bottle2`, `.bottle3` etc have wrong `letf` and `top` css properties; in addition, the `.side` divs miss the `background-image` property.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by $containers = [...document.querySelectorAll('.container')]

Comment: @billyrope `document.querySelectorAll('.container')` returns all elements that matches a specified selector (in your case `.container`) as a NodeList object. A NodeList object acts _almost_ like an array: almost, because it has items stored at numeric indices and a length property just like an Array, but it does not have have any of the other Array methods. This means that using `append` on a NodeList object item would raise an error. For this reason I pass the Items of a NodeList object in an Array using a **spread operator**. It's an ES6 solution.